# sysprep on Win10 exits with error RunExternalDlls:Not running DLLs

Tags: windows, windows-10, sysprep

I try to use sysprep on Win 10 Pro. I use these options:

- Generalize
- OOBE
- Shutdown

Log file setuperr.log shows:

```
[0x0f0073] SYSPRP RunExternalDlls:Not running DLLs; either the machine is in an invalid state or we couldn't update the recorded state, dwRet= 1f 
[0x0f00ae] SYSPRP WinMain:Hit failure while processing sysprep cleanup external providers; hr = 0x8007001f
```

sysprep window title shows another version: "System preparation tool 3.14"

Any idea for workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regedit to change the below registry keys to match:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Status\SysprepStatus\GeneralizationState\
CleanupState:2
GeneralizationState:7
```

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep yet to add this as a comment to the answer @joro gave.

The registry on the Win 10 Enterprise v22H2 box I was trying to sysprep didn't have a separate \GeneralizationState key, but the CleanupState and GeneralizationState values were present under the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Status\SysprepStatus key, and modifying them to the values @joro gave still worked.

So for my machine, the registry values that worked were:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Status\SysprepStatus]
"GeneralizationState"=dword:00000007
"CleanupState"=dword:00000002
```

So if you edit it manually, it should look something like this:
[registry screenshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20230502134541/https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufxHo.png)